# SharedPreferences returning default value after value is set

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sharedpreferences

I am having an issue with the Shared Preferences returning the default value after i've already set the value previously

Here is my methods to retrieve the value

```
private final Object timeSheetFilterUserLock = new Object();
public String getTimeSheetFilterUser(){
    synchronized (timeSheetFilterUserLock)
    {
        String user = getSharedPreferences().getString(TIMESHEET_FILTER_USER_ID, App.getOrLoadUserId());

        LogApp.i("User Get " + user);

        return user;
    }
}

public void setTimeSheetUser(String userID){
    synchronized (timeSheetFilterUserLock)
    {
        boolean success = getSharedPreferences().edit().putString(TIMESHEET_FILTER_USER_ID, userID).commit();

        LogApp.i("User Set " + userID);
        LogApp.i("Success " + (success ? "true" : "false"));
    }
}
```

I was synchronizing the methods to double check that it wasn't a threading issue (as most logic is done on worker threads)

The LogCat results are

```
2019-09-04 09:41:36.315 19226-19226/com.app I/APPMessage: User Get 4567A3EC-8BDC-417A-84D3-DA1A7E950ECE
2019-09-04 09:41:40.359 19226-19226/com.app I/APPMessage: User Set 784FFB1F-67E6-4778-B940-7B6EF19ECA16
2019-09-04 09:41:40.359 19226-19226/com.app I/APPMessage: Success true
2019-09-04 09:41:43.579 19226-19226/com.app I/APPMessage: User Get 89B0F277-B3D1-48BD-80F2-CEC00A069F34
2019-09-04 09:42:15.406 19226-19226/com.app I/APPMessage: User Get 784FFB1F-67E6-4778-B940-7B6EF19ECA16
```

So it looks like its trying to access the key/value pair, but is busy and returns a null value.

It also appears that if i call it again after the initial "Get" call, it returns the appropriate value.

What would be causing this and how would i make sure the correct value is returned? (I rather not put wait timers in the code)

Comment: Do you happen to be doing this in separate processes? Also, your default value – `App.getOrLoadUserId()` – seems to change in seconds. Why might that be?

Comment: I don't believe its on a separate processor, as the "Set" is being used on a fragment with ViewPager and the "Get" is being used on the fragment inside the viewPager.

The value "App.getOrLoadUserId() is the currently logged in user, so that value won't change unless the user logs out of the app.

It appears that its returning null, so the default value is being used (i've tested by placing "1" in the default value and then the logcat returned "1" to me

Comment: OK, yeah, unless you're launching some `Service` that's doing the sets/gets in a separate process, it sounds like you're just in one. As for the default value, I'm referring to the fact that you're printing `"User Get " + user` after the `getString()` call. If it is indeed returning the default value the first two times, then it looks like `App.getOrLoadUserId()` is changing, 'cause the first get prints `4567A3EC-8BDC-417A-84D3-DA1A7E950ECE`, and the second prints `89B0F277-B3D1-48BD-80F2-CEC00A069F34`.

Comment: If you're certain that `App.getOrLoadUserId()` is not changing, then I would have to say that you're writing that preference somewhere else, too, and it's getting mixed in with what you're expecting here. Given that this is in a `ViewPager`, it seems likely that the combination of how a `ViewPager` prepares and manages off-screen `Fragment`s, and the overall `Fragment` lifecycle, might be causing your issue.

Comment: That's what i was thinking, so i placed the logs into the methods for setting and getting the timesheet filter user. If we look at the LogCat results in the question we'll see that Get is called first (when loading the fragment), Set is then called (when changing the filter user), success is true, Then Get is called once reloading is called due to the update of filter user (This is the incorrect value (App.getOrLoadUserID value)), then on a sync it will reload (the final Get) to update and now shows the correct value

Comment: Is is possible that the "TIMESHEET_FILTER_USER_ID" pair is locked while setting the value, and if the query for GET is called on the key while its  locked it will return null?

Comment: Locked? No, not really, not like you're thinking. You can do reads immediately after a `commit()` just fine. Where is that odd, incorrect value coming from, then? If I'm following you're description correctly, there should only be two values printing; the original, and the updated. Where did `89B0F277-B3D1-48BD-80F2-CEC00A069F34` come from? Are you sure you're not writing that somewhere else? I don't mean with that `setTimeSheetUser()` method, necessarily. What is the value of `TIMESHEET_FILTER_USER_ID`? What is `getSharedPreferences()` returning, exactly? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: 89B0F277-B3D1-48BD-80F2-CEC00A069F34 is the value of App.getOrLoadUserID    getSharedPreferences is returning a SharedPreference singleton object retrieved on Application init, the only code occurances of the value of TIMESHEET_FILTER_USER_ID is in 3 areas, the setting of the object and the GET and SET method, i'd like to continue on with this chat after lunch! (1h)

Comment: OK, then where is `4567A3EC-8BDC-417A-84D3-DA1A7E950ECE` coming from? Again, from your description, there should only be two values in play; the default value, and the updated value. You've got three different values in the logs. And if `89B0F277-B3D1-48BD-80F2-CEC00A069F34` is indeed what `App.getOrLoadUserId()` is returning, then that doesn't really make any sense, because that's the _second_ "default" value printed. I dropped your code into a test project, with dummy values as needed, and it works as expected with a get/set/get in immediate succession. Please put together a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, say 4567A3EC-8BDC-417A-84D3-DA1A7E950ECE is User1, 784FFB1F-67E6-4778-B940-7B6EF19ECA16 is User2 and 89B0F277-B3D1-48BD-80F2-CEC00A069F34 is User3 (The currently logged in User), we're trying to filter a list of timesheets by user, we start on user 1, then change and set the filter to user 2, but the GET returns User3 (as its the default value), then, when i query the GET soon after again (without calling SET) i get the expected User2 result, this issue is difficult to replicate and happens maybe 25% of the time, otherwise it works as expected, making it difficult to show an example

Comment: Well, sorry, but I got nothin' else, then. I can't even begin to guess what might be the exact cause of this, beyond what I mentioned above, about the `ViewPager`/`Fragment` juggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much research i couldn't come up with a valid reason behind why this is happening. I was able to call the GET method twice, the first time i'd get my undesired result (the default value) and on the second call i received my expected result.

```
App.getSettingFilterApi().getTimeSheetFilterUser();
String storedUserID = App.getSettingFilterApi().getTimeSheetFilterUser();
```

The "fix" to this was to make a useless call to the sharedPreferences to "blow away" the undesired result and then call again for my expected result